# Are there any pretrained Malheur malware classification models or predefined datasets out there?

Tags: machine-learning

At my school's information security course we learned the basics of https://github.com/rieck/malheur

Are there any pretrained models?  I imagine a use-case where I have several pretrained models then run `classify` on the new malware on each of them to see which model's dataset the novel malware being classified should be incrementally added to.

Comment: Hmm, good question, but apparently the tool appears to be not maintained anymore for years...

Comment: Is malheur a part of any commercial malware detection/prevention systems?

Comment: It probably got implemented in some products I think, but not sure...

Comment: Questions asking for resources or "where can I find ...?" are off-topic as the potential answers are too dynamic